# Javascript : Using Switch to set variables values for the function

Tags: javascript

am totally new to Javascript , but i need it for using googlemaps in my project , am trying to set values for the latitude , longitude and map zoom for every certain city , so am getting the city name from a hidden form input and using Switch to switch regarding the city name .

```
cityDiv = document.getElementById('id_city');
cityDiv.value = idCity ;

switch (idCity)
{
case "city1":
    var map_long = 31.37667;
    var map_lat = 31.04306;
    var map_zoom = 3;
    break
case "city2":
    var map_long = 31.33333;
    var map_lat = 29.85;
    var map_zoom = 7;
    break
default:
    var map_long = 31.37667;
    var map_lat = 31.04306;
    var map_zoom = 3;
}

function onLoad() {
    map = new GMap(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.centerAndZoom(new GLatLng(map_lat,map_long) , map_zoom);

    GEvent.addListener(map, 'click', function(overlay, point) { 
        if (prev_pin) { 
            map.removeOverlay(prev_pin); 
            prev_pin = null; 
        } 
        //var yPoint = new YGeoPoint({{ place.latitude }},{{ place.longitude }});

        if (point) { 
            pin = new GMarker(point); 
            map.addOverlay(pin); 
            prev_pin = pin; 

            latDiv = document.getElementById('id_latitude');
            lngDiv = document.getElementById('id_longitude'); 
            lngDiv.value = point.x;
            latDiv.value = point.y; 
        } 
    });

}
```

Sorry for this newbie question .

Best regards .

EDIT from comment by geowa4:

The question and the problem are The Variables never set :( , so whats wrong with my code ?! i change "cityDiv.value = idCity ; " to " var idCity = cityDiv.value ; " which didn't work as well but this time the map refuses to load

Comment: The question and the problem  are The Variables never set :( , so whats wrong with my code ?!

i change "cityDiv.value = idCity ;
 " to " var idCity = cityDiv.value ; " 
which didn't work as well but this time the map refuses to load

Comment: P.s : am totally JS newbie :(

Comment: I put the question (from your comment) in the question, since that's where it belongs. Edit it further if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is scope, pure and simple. Using `var` scopes your variables to the current lexical scope, which in the case of `var map_long = 31.37667;` et al is the switch statement. Once you fall out of that scope, any variables declared in that scope vanish unless an external reference is maintained. You could remove the `var` statement, but that would make the variables global. I would recommend declaring your variables in a scope that makes sense to you, making them global only if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried dumping your values, stepping through and debugging? [Alert statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert), or [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) statements, to see what the page thinks the value of that select is?

You might also consider making an object, that you can then update:

```
// Untested, but you should get the gist
var cityInfo = {
    map_long : 0.0,
    map_lat : 0.0,
    map_zoom : 0
};

switch (idCity) {
case "city1":
    cityInfo.map_long = 31.37667;
    cityInfo.map_lat = 31.04306;
    cityInfo.map_zoom = 3;
    break
case "city2":
    cityInfo.map_long = 31.33333;
    cityInfo.map_lat = 29.85;
    cityInfo.map_zoom = 7;
    break
default:
    cityInfo.map_long = 31.37667;
    cityInfo.map_lat = 31.04306;
    cityInfo.map_zoom = 3;
}
```

Comment: This seems more reasonable -- I wonder if those variables he has in the original example are locally scoped to the switch statement.

Comment: hmm i tried this but didn't work as well , as a newbie i didn't debug much javascript yet but now am doing that now .  

@Meredith , i don't know if they locally scoped or not , but its the same as i listed in the example above !

Comment: Just a note, the above code does not work because the cityInfo variable is declared incorrectly. It's an associative array so change those semicolons to commas, and the equals signs to colons and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks, coderjoe. You're absolutely right. I was bouncing through a few different scripting languages at the time I wrote it.

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below:

```
mapInfo = 
{
  "city1":
  {
    "long": 31.37667,
    "lat": 31.04306,
    "zoom": 3
  },
  "city2":
  {
    "long": 31.33333,
    "lat": 29.85,
    "zoom": 7
  }
};

function onLoad() {
    map = new GMap(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    var cityDiv = document.getElementById('id_city');
    var idCity = cityDiv.value || "city1";
    map.centerAndZoom(new GLatLng(mapInfo[idCity].lat,mapInfo[idCity].long) , mapInfo[idCity].zoom);

    GEvent.addListener(map, 'click', function(overlay, point) { 
        if (prev_pin) { 
                map.removeOverlay(prev_pin); 
                prev_pin = null; 
        } 
        //var yPoint = new YGeoPoint({{ place.latitude }},{{ place.longitude }});

        if (point) { 
                pin = new GMarker(point); 
                map.addOverlay(pin); 
                prev_pin = pin; 

                latDiv = document.getElementById('id_latitude');
                lngDiv = document.getElementById('id_longitude'); 
                lngDiv.value = point.x;
                latDiv.value = point.y; 
        } 
    });

}
```

Comment: Its Working perfectly , Thank you very much , as a newbie and self-educational nerd am still trying to figure out How , What , and Why . BUT Thank you VERY MUCH

Comment: Wondering those questions indicates that you are or probably will be a good programmer ;) Well your code had 2 problems. First one was the variable scope problem which was suggested by the previous answers. When you use "var" in JS, you variables are valid for only the current code block and its sub blocks. When you remove that, the variables immediately becomes a property of the global "window" object. And the second one, well I'm not a fan of "switch" statements so I just used the advantage of JS objects acting like associative arrays.

Comment: @BYK : I analyze the code and read more about how to deal with variables , its very easy , but some how very tricky , i do programming in some other languages , but somehow i Hate javascript and don't used to deal with it that much , using jQuery for small tasks and effects . Hope that'll be  help me in self-study way for JS . Thank you